How can I use Tanstack Query useMutation like this
I want to use useMutation like useQuery. So I have tried this but this code is not working like my expectation. Here data is coming undefined and isError is false, why? How can I solve this issue?
`import { useMutation } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";


export const useUserx = () => {
    const loginKey = localStorage.getItem("login_key");
    const memberId = localStorage.getItem("member_id");

    const viewUserProfileData = {
        login_key: loginKey, 
        member_id: memberId
    }

    const {data, isError, isLoading } = useMutation({
        mutationKey: ["user-mutate"],
        mutationFn: async () => {
            const response = await axios.post('https://example.com/user/profile',     
            viewUserProfileData )
            console.log(response);
            return response?.data;
        }
    })

    return {data, isError, isLoading }
}`


useMutate will return you two mutate functions (mutate and mutateAsync) which you need to call in order to actually trigger the mutation. So something like this:
import { useMutation } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";

export const useUserx = () => {
    const loginKey = localStorage.getItem("login_key");
    const memberId = localStorage.getItem("member_id");

    const viewUserProfileData = {
        login_key: loginKey, 
        member_id: memberId
    }

    return useMutation({
        mutationKey: ["user-mutate"],
        mutationFn: async () => {
            const response = await axios.post('https://example.com/user/profile',     
            viewUserProfileData )
            console.log(response);
            return response?.data;
        }
    })
}

export const UserxComponent = () => {
  const { mutate, isError } = useUserx()

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => mutate()}>Do stuff</button>
      {isError && <span>There was an error</span>}
    </div> 
  )
}

Please note that I returned the whole object from useMutation
